# Issue with IOS Http POST

Tags: ios, objective-c

Request data

```
NSDictionary *tmp = @{@"name":@"Kousik",@"age":@"24",@"location":@"bangalore"};

NSString *postdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"request = %@",tmp];

//now postdata is
//request = {
    "age" = "24";
    "location" = "bangalore";
    "name" = "Kousik";
}
```

but I want this NSDictionary should be inside a string so that in server I can `eval` it and get the dictionary back.

Here I want something like `toString()` is java or `str()` in pyhton.

This is my Http request:-

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSError *error;

    NSData *preparedPostData = [postdata dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postdata length]];
    
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:preparedPostData ]; 


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:backgroundQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse response,NSData data,NSError *error){
                           NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           if(complect)
                               complect(result,error);
                       }
 ];
```

## Update

My request is going to server properly but The problem is with data structure.
when I am trying to access the data with `request` key then it is giving error because the value for the request key is not supported in server as this value is having `=` sign in between. So what I want is that to make the requset data structure properly.want to send the NSDictionary itself as a string.

postdata should be something like this

```
request =  "{
        age : 24;
        location : bangalore;
        name : Kousik;
    }"
```

I dont want to use application/json.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Dont take parameter in dictionary, but take it into string.

Comment: my requirement is like that.So I may sent dictionary inside a dictioanry also.but this will go as a string.

Comment: POST requests have similar to query string format. Format your body properly or use JSON which is easier to produce with NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&age=%@&location=%@",@"Kousik",@"24",@"bangalore"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ServerURL,API_SaveContctListToAddressBook]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[stringURL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    //    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if (!data) {
                                   data = [[NSData alloc] init];
                               }
                               NSDictionary *dic =[ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&connectionError];

                               completionHandler(dic, NO);


                           }];
```

Comment: My Http requset is working fine but the problem is with request data structure.

Comment: your stringURL is not containing any dictionary

Comment: its working but my question is different.try to prepare the stringURL  from a dictionary.

Comment: you take dictionary in string so that Dictionary save as string. so you get error

Comment: request =  "{ age : 24; location : bangalore; name : Kousik; }" IT is string with inside dictionary. Its wrong

Comment: why did you hardcode that? try to prepare it dynamically.because that dictionary may contain another dictionary and both dictionary may have the one common key. so whatever you are doing I can't do that.

Comment: yes it is also possible in string as dynamically data.

Comment: I know your code is woking as per your expectation but you are not getting my point. I am saying try to load the stringURL  from a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Use NSJSONSerialization to convert your dictionary to NSData and then attach it on HTTPBody

```
NSData *httpBody = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ServerURL,APIPath]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:httpBody];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
//Handling code
                       }];
```

Comment: is it possible with using application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: If you're using application/x-www-form-urlencoded then you should pass all the parameters '&' separated something like this:-  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&age=%@&location=%@",@"Kousik",@"24",@"bangalore"];